# JsonValueProvider doesn't seem to work in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have not been able to STOP reading about how great and wonderful `JsonValueProvider` in ASP.NET MVC is, and I am trying very desperately to make it work, but this result is getting excessively frustrating. I have been bashing my face against this for days and days, and it is just to a point where I have no clue what is going wrong.

Using the following Controller Action..

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Character(ViewModels.CreateCharacterViewModel model) {

    // if the character model is valid, we can go ahead and start looking at creating it.
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

With this AJAX post...

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/member/create/character',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {
        model: JSON.stringify(viewModel)
    }
});
```

I am receiving the error `Invalid JSON Primitive` when I try to post, this is my data...

```
{
  "Name": "Test Name",
  "Age": "21",
  "Gender": "None",
  "Points": [

  ],
  "Race": {
    "Id": "races/4",
    "Name": "Test Race",
    "Url": "description-url.html",
    "Description": null,
    "Genders": [
      "None"
    ],
    "Lifespan": {
      "Minimum": 0,
      "Maximum": 10000000
    },
    "Points": null
  }
}
```

It should correspond to this C# view model

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines a view model for creating a new character.
/// </summary>
public class CreateCharacterViewModel {

    /// <summary>
    /// The character's name as it will appear on the character sheet, and on the roster.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [RegularExpression(Text.RegularExpressions.Name, ErrorMessage = Text.ErrorMessages.Name)]
    [Display(Name = "Character Name")]
    [Rules("The name of the character. Names must be between 3 and 64 characters in length, may contain any alphanumeric character and the symbols -', and spaces only.")]
    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The email address of the character.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(Text.RegularExpressions.Email, ErrorMessage = Text.ErrorMessages.Email)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Rules("The email address for the character. This does not have to be unique. You can't use: <em>[ ] | ; , $ \\ < > \" or any spaces.</em>")]
    public string Email {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The character's age in standard years.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [Integer]
    [Display(Name = "Character Age")]
    [Rules("The character's current age, given in years. This field is required, even if your character is not aware of their own age.")]
    public int Age {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The character's selected race
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Race")]
    [Rules("The character's race. You may select from our pre-defined templates, or select 'custom' if the race you wish to make does not exist.")]
    public Models.Races.Race Race {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The character's selected gender.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    [Rules("The character's gender. This must be selected. Not all possible options are available to all races.")]
    public string Gender {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Where the Races part matches this Model...

```
public class Race : IHasIdentity, IHasName, IMayTemplate {
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique identity of the race.
    /// </summary>
    public string Id {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The unique name of the race.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The URL that points to the race's detail page.
    /// </summary>
    public string Url {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The description of the race.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The genders available to the race.
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> Genders {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The race's expected lifespan
    /// </summary>
    public Lifespan Lifespan {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The various customization points that the race has to spend.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Points> Points {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/member/create/character',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(viewModel)
});
```

or if you wanna explicitly specify the name of your action argument:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/member/create/character',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ model: viewModel })
});
```

Notice how the entire `data` property is sent as JSON.stringify in my example whereas in yours you are sending only the `model` property as JSON.

Comment: oh my god you are my new best friend in the universe. Yes, that is exactly what was wrong. This seems like such a very obscure behavior. Now that I see it in writing, it makes perfect sense, but I've never seen it shown like this anywhere else.

Comment: I assume what this means is that we want to turn the ENTIRE input into one supermassive JSON string, and leave any parameter names within that, instead of sending each individual parameter.

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me. I do not have enough ways to express how much more of my hair you just saved me.